# Dynamically changing javascript function for efficiency

Tags: javascript

My question has to do with optimizing my javascript code to be more efficient.

I have a function that is called frequently but all the code inside is only needed to be called once, like so:

```
function removeBlankCanvas() {
    if ( --numberOfChartsStillLoading == 0 ) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine but the function is still called countless times after *numberOfChartsStillLoading* is 0, and I know it will never be 0 again. So I'm thinking about doing something like this:

```
function removeBlankCanvas() {
    if ( --numberOfChartsStillLoading == 0 ) {
        //do stuff

        removeBlankCanvas = function() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Could this be more efficient code? For instance, if the function was called millions of times? I'm asking strictly for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your performance bottleneck is very unlikely to be a simple if statement.

This trick could actually cause unexpected result, because functions are immutable, and you are very likely to have callbacks that will keep a reference to the original function, even after you changed the name reference to another function.

My 2 cents: find real performance issues to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create custom event and attached to the caller. 
You can remove the event from caller based on any condition you want.